# React className changes but CSS style do not

Tags: css, reactjs, classname

I have four classnames, lets call them red-0, red-1, blue-0, blue-1

The CSS for red-0 and red-1 is the same, and the CSS for blue-0 and blue-1 is the same.

My React component are changing the classNames just as I want. My problem is that it seems like the React component ignores the CSS styling when I apply a classname with the same CSS it had right before the state change. Is this an actual case? Because my CSS changes perfectly when it goes from e.g. red-0 to blue-0, but not from red-0 to red-1.

If you have a suggestion of how I can solve this problem, I would be greatful.

**A buddy helped me:**

The trix was to add a promise and first set the state to an empty classname, and then add the classname that i wanted inside the promise, like this:

this.setState({ className: '' }, () => this.setState({ className: 'red-0' }));

The reason for having four classnames instead of two was because I hoped the classname change would trigger a new animation, but it did not, even though it triggered new regular CSS changes. I ended up using only two classnames: red and blue

Comment: a relevant code snippet will he helpful for others in solving your problem

Comment: what is the problem exactly?  If both `red-0` and `red-1` are the same isn't it doing the right thing?

Comment: For my own curiosity, can you please do `this.forceUpdate()` at the end of whatever event handler is changing the class names

Comment: @DavinTryon He most likely is doing some conditional work based on the class name.

Comment: @ReidunMarie please try adding `this.forceUpdate()` at the end of whatever event handler is changing the classname and tell me if the new classnames are showing as you expect. Then reply so we know whether you're seeing results.

Comment: Please add your code